# How to replace the character A with T and T with A

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to create a program that will take a string and reverse it and replace it with its complimentary characters.

For example, if the string "ATTGCC" is input, the method `reverse_it` should output "GGCAAT".

"A" is replaced by "T", and "T" is replaced by "A". "C" is replaced by "G", and "G" is replaced by "C".

This is my code:

```
class DNA
  def initialize (nucleotide)
    @nucleotide = nucleotide
  end
  def reverse_it()
    puts nucleotide.reverse.gsub("C", "G").gsub("G", "C").gsub("A", "T").gsub("T", "A")
  end
  protected

  attr_reader :nucleotide
end
dna1 = DNA.new("ATTGCC")
dna1.reverse_it
```

The problem is `gsub` replaces all occurrences of the character and `sub` replaces only the first instance of the character in the string. Is there a built-in method to make this program work?

Comment: You can replace the `A`s with `X`s then the `T`s with `A`s then the `X`s with `T`s for an easy, understandable way of doing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably looking for [tr](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-tr), so in your method instead of `gsub`, something like:

```
nucleotide.reverse.tr "ATCG", "TAGC"
```

Comment: Good ol' `tr`, the forgotten method. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If there are numerous letter-pairs to reverse, you could save yourself some typing and reduce the chance of incorrect entries as follows.

```
h = Hash[ *%w| C G   A T   B S   W X | ]
  #=> {"C"=>"G", "A"=>"T", "B"=>"S", "W"=>"X"} 
h.update h.invert
  #=> {"C"=>"G", "A"=>"T", "B"=>"S", "W"=>"X", "G"=>"C", "T"=>"A", "S"=>"B", "X"=>"W"} 
s = "tac ATTWBGXCXSCWB god".reverse.gsub(Regexp.union(h.keys), h)
  #=> "dog SXGBWGWCSXAAT cat"
```

and, of course:

```
s.reverse.gsub(Regexp.union(h.keys), h)
  #=> "tac ATTWBGXCXSCWB god"
```